# How to add differnt sub ObservableCollections to main ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, generics, collections, observablecollection

**Example**

I have

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> // 1
ObservableCollection<Boss>// 2
ObservableCollection<Department> //3

ObservableCollection<T> // main >>>I want 1, 2, 3 ObservableCollection to main ObservableCollection
```

**How to do?**

edited1: I want to add them to be a list. Not for each item.

edited2: I have to display 3 lists of field on the wpf application. the 2nd list can add/remove item in the list.

** please let me know if it unclear.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve and/or what you've already tried please?

Comment: Is the question: "How to make an `ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>>` where `T` changes per collection that would be added?"

Comment: @mlorbetske yes, it is "How to make an ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<T>> where T changes per collection that would be added?"

Comment: @user2617677 would making that wrapper collection a `ObservableCollection<IList>` work in your scenario?

Comment: @mlorbetske sorry, please describe me more, i don't understand what you said. I im not good in english.

Comment: @user2617677 `var wrapper = new ObservableCollection<IList>(); wrapper.Add(departments); wrapper.Add(employees);` should be valid, but I don't know if it will work with whatever binding you're doing.

Comment: Thank you all, I will try it and after that i will feedback what it happen. maybe, i have to change something. I will discuss my boss first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since what you want to do is to add a collection to a collection, but those collection types are not compatible, I'd try this

```
ObservableCollection<Employee> _employees = ...
ObservableCollection<Boss> _bosses = ...
ObservableCollection<Department> _departments = ...


ObservableCollection<IList> _collections = ...
_collections.Add(_employees);
_collections.Add(_bosses);
_collections.Add(_departments);
```

Note that the generic argument to the `_collections` collection is `IList`. `ObservableCollection<T>` implements `IList` and is therefore assignable to things of that type, even for different `T`s among the sets.

Comment: ObservableCollection<IList> is a good idea, a collection of lists. +!

Answer (score 0):

Observable Collection does not support something like `AddRange` functionality where in you can add your entire list to an already existing list.

By the way, if all your observable collection is of type T, you could use `foreach` to iterate through and do the `adding`, something like below:

```
        var observableCollection1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        foreach (var element in observableCollection1)
        {
            observableCollection.Add(element);
        }
```

But, what you are trying to do, as from my understanding, is trying to add an `observable collection of type department` to a `different type T`, which is not possible unless you try to add it to an `observable collection of simply, objects`. Warning: Note, you might need to box/unbox afterwards.

**`Code Snippet:`**

```
        var observableCollection_Department = new ObservableCollection<Department>();
        var observableCollection_Employee = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
        var observableCollection_Boss = new ObservableCollection<Boss>();

        var observableCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();

        foreach (var element in observableCollection_Department)
        {
            observableCollection.Add(element);
        }

        foreach (var element in observableCollection_Employee)
        {
            observableCollection.Add(element);
        }

        foreach (var element in observableCollection_Boss)
        {
            observableCollection.Add(element);
        }
```